# Cloud build definition update to include submodule

Tags: unity3d-cloud-build

We have a repo that has the submodule dependencies.

1. Can we have the cloud build definition updated to include the submodule as a part of cloud build? Any reference to the wiki/doc will help us here.
2. Is there any authentication needed here?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the above issue. Cloudbuild need not be updated for any submodule changes. Just adding the submodule itself will make sure to update git config to build submodule. Make sure to add the submodule under root\src on your repo.